# Elixir versioning with SCSS and JavaScript

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-elixir

How do I chain Elixir's .version() method with others? My gulpfile.js looks like this:

```
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.sass("frontend/frontend.scss", "public/css/app.css")
       .sass("backend/backend.scss", "public/css/admin.css")
       .scripts(js, "public/js/app.js");
});
```

Do I just call .version() after this chain on my generated files? Like this:

```
elixir(function(mix) {
    mix.sass("frontend/frontend.scss", "public/css/app.css")
       .sass("backend/backend.scss", "public/css/admin.css")
       .scripts(js, "public/js/app.js")
       .version(["public/css/app.css", "public/css/admin.css", "public/js/app.js"]);
});
```

Or is there some way to combine .sass() and .scripts() methods with .version() to avoid repeating file names?

Another problem with my example is that it produces redundant unversioned files prior to creating versioned ones, so I have useless files there.

Answer (score 1):

You said it. The only way to version based on what the laravel docs says is too chain `.version([path_to_public_file])`. If you would like to make sure for yourself, the docs are here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/elixir.

Comment: I have seen the docs, but I don't think this is the proof that there is no other way.

Comment: I know, ill check out the api's to make sure

Comment: I looked around a bit and as far as I can see that's the only possible way to do it.